# How to get all elements of a dropdown from desktop application into a collection in blue prism

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to change the font of something written in notepad through blue prism.Notepad being a desktop application,i m trying to do it using Win32 mode.In this case,the list box is identified as Element type Window.

Then on using Read stage,the only action available to fetch all the elements into collection is " Get Text".This doesnt help in fetching all values in collection.

I have tried changing the element type manually to list Box.But of no use.

I expect to change the font in notepad by selecting a particular font,size and style.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're barking up the wrong tree a bit, as the items in question are Win32 Combo Boxes. However, it's a bit difficult to spy these elements using the traditional Blue Prism point-and-click spy mode.

You can spy the attributes for these items using the Application Navigator, which can be opened using the Identify sub-menu within the Application Modeler window:

[image: Open Application Navigator menu item]

From the resulting window, you can use the filtering functionality to filter out items that don't match an expected attribute for the combo box you're looking for. In this case, since I know the Combo Box I'm looking for's current value is `Consolas`, I've filtered out all elements that don't have an attribute value matching the string `Consolas`. I then used a bit of trial and error until I found the correct element:

[image: Application Navigator window]

From there, I clicked OK and imported the attributes to my Application Modeler entry. With a few small adjustments to my matching parameters, I was able to successfully use a Read stage to collect all the available Font options into a Collection for further processing:

[image: List of Fonts extracted from Notepad]